# matplotlib surface plot artifact: curving back around?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, quantitative-finance

The surface that I'm plotting with `matplotlib` is giving me a strange artifact. The desired surface is concave up with respect to both `x` and `y`, but there is also a flat one that is being displayed. My `y` values that are creating a closed loop instead of a "line" when viewed from the `y-z` side. I'm attaching pictures to show what's going on. The surface that I want is the bottom on; the one on top (the flat one) is the artifact.

[default view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i08lz.png)

[y,z side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeGO0.png)

I'm also including my code below. The visualization is for the results of a Monte Carlo simulation where I'm stepping through 2 input parameters and savings results in the following way:

`[ [VIP1, VIP2, FIP, avg_ret, max_ret, min_ret] , ... ]` where

```
- VIP1 = input parameter 1
- VIP2 = input parameter 2
- FIP = fixed input parameter
- avg_, max_, min_ret = average, max, and min returns from the Monte Carlo simulation results.
```

I'm plotting `avg_ret` as a function of `VIP1` and `VIP2` such that they are `z`, `x`, `y` respectively.

Since `z` needs to be a 2-dimensional array based on the `x`, `y` grid created by `np.meshgrid()`, I had to create it myself with a nested `for` loop. I transformed the `z` results to a `dictionary` to help with this.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

%matplotlib notebook

# monte carlo simulations happen here

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = list(x[0] for x in sim_returns) # VIP1
y = list(x[1] for x in sim_returns) # VIP2
z = list(x[3] for x in sim_returns) # avg_ret

# need to build a dictionary of dictionaries for creating a surface plot in order to have Z be a function of X and Y
z_dict = {} # create dictionary
for row in sim_returns:
    if row[0] not in z_dict.keys():
        z_dict[row[0]]={}
        z_dict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[3]
    else:
        z_dict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[3]


x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# creating the z_grid to have it be a 2-dimensional array for plotting
z_grid = []
z_grid_inner = []
for x in range(len(x_grid)):
    z_grid_inner = []
    for y in range(len(x_grid[0])):
        z_grid_inner.append(z_dict[x_grid[x][y]][y_grid[x][y]])
    z_grid.append(z_grid_inner)

# need to wrap z_grid with np.asarray() otherwise get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'"
ax.plot_surface(x_grid, y_grid, np.asarray(z_grid), cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('VIP1')
ax.set_ylabel('VIP2')
ax.set_zlabel('avg_ret')

plt.show()
```

---

Data for debugging:
(this is what the for loops return for `x`, `y`, `z` variable assignments)

```
x = [60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]

y = [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01]

z = [0.06, 0.208, 0.399, 0.692, 0.922, 1.172, 1.618, 2.036, 2.5, 2.986, 0.109, 0.316, 0.591, 0.875, 1.181, 1.644, 2.141, 2.637, 3.532, 4.371, 0.124, 0.358, 0.658, 0.976, 1.396, 1.884, 2.42, 3.25, 3.843, 5.144, 0.164, 0.427, 0.73, 1.134, 1.679, 2.225, 2.821, 3.751, 4.646, 5.687, 0.202, 0.478, 0.81, 1.24, 1.844, 2.51, 3.253, 4.364, 5.475, 7.05, 0.223, 0.541, 0.925, 1.433, 2.026, 2.793, 3.811, 5.039, 6.43, 8.047, 0.254, 0.581, 1.017, 1.578, 2.252, 3.119, 4.212, 5.689, 7.68, 9.58, 0.286, 0.654, 1.127, 1.735, 2.514, 3.515, 4.8, 6.448, 8.563, 11.274]

sim_returns = [[60, 0.001, 0.001, 0.041, 0.051, 0.032], [60, 0.002, 0.001, 0.219, 0.252, 0.204], [60, 0.003, 0.001, 0.428, 0.455, 0.393], [60, 0.004, 0.001, 0.653, 0.78, 0.563], [60, 0.005, 0.001, 0.971, 1.038, 0.885], [60, 0.006, 0.001, 1.183, 1.31, 1.023], [60, 0.007, 0.001, 1.495, 1.921, 1.355], [60, 0.008, 0.001, 1.859, 2.121, 1.632], [60, 0.009, 0.001, 2.46, 2.787, 2.327], [60, 0.01, 0.001, 3.112, 3.734, 2.64], [70, 0.001, 0.001, 0.111, 0.121, 0.103], [70, 0.002, 0.001, 0.325, 0.382, 0.278], [70, 0.003, 0.001, 0.585, 0.674, 0.503], [70, 0.004, 0.001, 0.914, 0.997, 0.843], [70, 0.005, 0.001, 1.223, 1.339, 1.151], [70, 0.006, 0.001, 1.613, 1.848, 1.425], [70, 0.007, 0.001, 2.145, 2.292, 1.968], [70, 0.008, 0.001, 2.783, 2.94, 2.635], [70, 0.009, 0.001, 3.44, 3.668, 2.712], [70, 0.01, 0.001, 4.322, 4.703, 4.0], [75, 0.001, 0.001, 0.138, 0.155, 0.118], [75, 0.002, 0.001, 0.363, 0.378, 0.349], [75, 0.003, 0.001, 0.641, 0.681, 0.589], [75, 0.004, 0.001, 1.004, 1.131, 0.918], [75, 0.005, 0.001, 1.301, 1.367, 1.229], [75, 0.006, 0.001, 1.892, 2.119, 1.637], [75, 0.007, 0.001, 2.76, 3.019, 2.426], [75, 0.008, 0.001, 3.095, 3.31, 2.905], [75, 0.009, 0.001, 4.32, 4.812, 3.955], [75, 0.01, 0.001, 4.859, 5.225, 4.518], [80, 0.001, 0.001, 0.157, 0.176, 0.148], [80, 0.002, 0.001, 0.432, 0.472, 0.411], [80, 0.003, 0.001, 0.755, 0.828, 0.721], [80, 0.004, 0.001, 1.103, 1.131, 1.057], [80, 0.005, 0.001, 1.611, 1.782, 1.439], [80, 0.006, 0.001, 2.231, 2.344, 2.097], [80, 0.007, 0.001, 3.038, 3.352, 2.74], [80, 0.008, 0.001, 3.718, 4.065, 3.548], [80, 0.009, 0.001, 4.745, 4.988, 4.529], [80, 0.01, 0.001, 6.022, 6.749, 5.503], [85, 0.001, 0.001, 0.2, 0.219, 0.192], [85, 0.002, 0.001, 0.46, 0.494, 0.437], [85, 0.003, 0.001, 0.812, 0.85, 0.756], [85, 0.004, 0.001, 1.256, 1.343, 1.184], [85, 0.005, 0.001, 1.847, 1.867, 1.816], [85, 0.006, 0.001, 2.42, 2.536, 2.344], [85, 0.007, 0.001, 3.265, 3.422, 3.083], [85, 0.008, 0.001, 4.445, 4.691, 4.157], [85, 0.009, 0.001, 5.492, 5.816, 5.108], [85, 0.01, 0.001, 6.793, 7.366, 6.417], [90, 0.001, 0.001, 0.232, 0.238, 0.219], [90, 0.002, 0.001, 0.518, 0.544, 0.494], [90, 0.003, 0.001, 0.892, 0.925, 0.865], [90, 0.004, 0.001, 1.426, 1.475, 1.39], [90, 0.005, 0.001, 2.076, 2.174, 1.919], [90, 0.006, 0.001, 2.841, 2.982, 2.74], [90, 0.007, 0.001, 3.839, 4.146, 3.639], [90, 0.008, 0.001, 4.902, 5.115, 4.54], [90, 0.009, 0.001, 6.504, 6.993, 6.164], [90, 0.01, 0.001, 8.463, 8.86, 8.033], [95, 0.001, 0.001, 0.257, 0.271, 0.251], [95, 0.002, 0.001, 0.603, 0.625, 0.577], [95, 0.003, 0.001, 1.015, 1.036, 1.004], [95, 0.004, 0.001, 1.571, 1.628, 1.537], [95, 0.005, 0.001, 2.257, 2.37, 2.081], [95, 0.006, 0.001, 3.241, 3.36, 3.095], [95, 0.007, 0.001, 4.34, 4.485, 4.146], [95, 0.008, 0.001, 5.762, 5.933, 5.569], [95, 0.009, 0.001, 7.37, 7.656, 7.154], [95, 0.01, 0.001, 9.615, 10.368, 8.968], [100, 0.001, 0.001, 0.286, 0.286, 0.286], [100, 0.002, 0.001, 0.654, 0.654, 0.654], [100, 0.003, 0.001, 1.127, 1.127, 1.127], [100, 0.004, 0.001, 1.735, 1.735, 1.735], [100, 0.005, 0.001, 2.514, 2.514, 2.514], [100, 0.006, 0.001, 3.515, 3.515, 3.515], [100, 0.007, 0.001, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8], [100, 0.008, 0.001, 6.448, 6.448, 6.448], [100, 0.009, 0.001, 8.563, 8.563, 8.563], [100, 0.01, 0.001, 11.274, 11.274, 11.274]]
```

Comment: Can you share same minimal data so that we can reproduce the error and help debugging?

Comment: @Bazingaa I edited the post and included the graph data at the bottom.

Comment: It's time to sleep in my country. I will get back to you tomorrow. Hope you get an answer by someone before that

Comment: Ok, I can't proceed as I need `sim_returns ` to create `z_dict`

Comment: @Bazingaa Just added `sim_returns` to the very bottom of the question. I appreciate your help with this so far. I still haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: Hmm. I tried playing with your code but couldn't find anything wrong. For me `np.asarray(z_grid)` was not even necessary and just `z_grid` reproduced the plot.  If I were you, I would try if the problem exists even when plotting with Mayavi.

Comment: @Bazingaa Did the artifact seen in my picture manifest in your plot? Would you mind post a screenshot of the plot you see from your end? I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the issue, but I'm using a cloud Jupyter notebook hosted on Azure and using Python 3.6

Comment: I got **exactly** the same figure as yours so I am not sure if posting will help. I am using Python 3.6 too. I don't think it has to do with that. Did you try using mayavi?